# Pyspark - group by column and collect unique set of values from a column of arrays of integers

Tags: python, pyspark

I need some help with the following issue.

I have a pyspark dataframe with two columns:

```
+----------------------+------+
|             col_list | group|
+----------------------+------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] |group1|
|            [6, 7, 8] |group1|
|         [1, 2, 3, 4] |group2|
|             [10, 11] |group2|
+----------------------+------+
```

And I want to do a groupby the column named `group` and collect unique values only into one list from column `col_list`.

I have tried this:

```
df.groupby("group").agg(F.flatten(F.collect_set('col_list')))
```

and it responded with this answer:

```
+------+-------------------------------+
| group|flatten(collect_set(col_list)) |
+------+-------------------------------+
|group1|          [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,7,8]|
|group2|          [10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4] |
+------+-------------------------------+
```

The group1 flatten list has duplicates and I need some help with only returning unique values like:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Comment: just use `F.array_distinct()` to remove duplicates from the flattened list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick - you need to `explode()` first, then `collect_set()`:

```py
df.select("group", F.explode(F.col("col_list")).alias("col_list")).groupby("group").agg(F.collect_set('col_list'))
```